# libvlc and sout option

Tags: vlc, libvlc

I would like to use the sout option in libvlc like in the corresponding command line:

```
vlc rtsp://address --sout '#duplicate{dst=display,dst=standard{access=file,mux=ts,dst=/tmp/go.mpg}}'
```

but unfortunately, it's not taken into account. I was told that sout is not implemented (yet) in libvlc. Any idea how I could find a solution? I'm basically just trying to dump on file the rtsp stream that is played on screen. There is not really any transcoding here - just a dump. If it's not possible, is there a good place I could patch libvlc and simply dump the stream on file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After enabling sout, the magic line in libvlc turned out to be:

```
libvlc_media_add_option(p_md, ":sout=#stream_out_duplicate{dst=display,dst=std{access=file,mux=ts,dst=/sdcard/go.mpg}}");
```